# How to blur entire body except div on target using only css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
     :not(:target) {
        filter: blur(5px);
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#test">test</a>
</body>

</html>
```

but even when I target (click) my test  it keeps blurred.

Comment: You are including `body` in the `:not()` selector. And since `a` is a child of `body` it will inherit the blur property. Try `body :not(<selector>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
body :not(:target) {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```css
body :not(:target) {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#test">test</a>
<p id="test">This is Target</p>
<p>This is'nt Target</p>
```

Comment: There should probably be a note stating that this would work **only** if the `:target` element is a direct child of the body. Otherwise, the filter would still be applied on the parent and hence would affect the `:target` element, and also applied as many times on all other elements as they are nested.

Comment: hi @Kaiido, Tkank you for comment. why direct child? i dont use `body > :not(:target)`.

Comment: Because there is no way to apply a filter on a parent element and not on its children. So if OP goes wrapping its elements in an other element, then this other element would be filtered, applying its own filter on its children, even the `:target` one. Just try to wrap all your elements in a `<div>`. https://jsfiddle.net/0p8wf58d/

Comment: @Ehsan Maybe add extra information [what browser that supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) this feature.